# How to make carousel-caption appear on top?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a simple bootstrap 4 carousel, I would like a carousel caption to appear on top instead of bottom something like this below.

[image]

> **update: HERE IS JSFIDLE WITH FULL CODE**

[carousel demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ys9bLkjc/)

Here is what I have tried so far

HTML

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <div class="pull-left">My Gallery Title</div>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                  </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

                    <!-- Indicators -->
                    <ul class="carousel-indicators">
                      <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                      <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                      <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                    </ul>

                    <!-- The slideshow -->
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                      <div class="carousel-item active">
                            <div class="carousel-caption">
                                    <h3>Heading 1</h3>
                                    </div>
                        <img src="https://placeimg.com/600/400/nature/1" alt="Los Angeles">
                      </div>
                      <div class="carousel-item">
                            <div class="carousel-caption">
                                    <h3>Heading 2</h3>
                                    </div>
                        <img src="https://placeimg.com/600/400/nature/2" alt="Chicago">
                      </div>
                      <div class="carousel-item">
                            <div class="carousel-caption">
                                    <h3>Heading 3</h3>
                                    </div>
                        <img src="https://placeimg.com/600/400/nature/3" alt="New York">
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Left and right controls -->
                    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
                      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
                      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
                    </a>
                  </div>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn-sm close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <!--end modal-footer-->
            </div>
            <!--end modal-content-->
        </div>
        <!--end modal-dialoge-->
    </div>
    <!--end myModal-->>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.carousel-caption {
    position: absolute;
    right: 15%;
    top: -42px;
    left: 15%;
    z-index: 999999999;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Unfortunately, with this solution, my carousel caption disappear.

What do I need to do to get what I want?

Comment: Can you put complete css code of the carousel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `css` of `.carousel-caption`

```
.carousel-item .carousel-caption {
  position: static;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/6bwkz4ph/)

Comment: hii @zuber I have updated my question check it , i have added full code

Comment: @user9964622 i have added working fiddle link. please check.

Comment: can you please read the question , by the way I found the answer

Comment: @user9964622 please check my updated answer and fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/6bwkz4ph/

Answer (score 1):

Change the value of top to 0. The carousel caption will move to top of your carousel exactly opposite to carousel indicators.
Try using the inspect element and check the position of your concern element.

Comment: @ user9964622 Increase the value of top to some +20 or +30 px so that it moves out of the carousel carousel.

Answer (score 0):

Use property relative in div with class ".carousel-item"

```
.carousel-item{
  position:relative;
}
.carousel-caption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
  z-index: 999999999;
  padding-top: 5px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Full working example in codepen: 
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bJygvj

Comment: by the way .carousel-item by default its relative , u can try urself and tell me if you can get  what I want?

Comment: this is a carousel of boostrap?

Comment: Only change the value of property top to 0, work it!

Comment: nope, you all please read the question carefully and check what exactly I want

Comment: Well you need to create a new css and modify the CSS of the class ".carousel-caption" and add it after the bootstrap css. 
Is this what you are asking?